# What does the > symbol do in the sum command in R?

Tags: r

I am transferring a code from R to Excel because the R code breaks when I use it. I ran in to a formula that is sum(X/X >Y/Y)/N, and I can't figure out what it is doing.

I tried running the code but it doesn't work.

variable1 <- sum(lambdaC/omegaC > lambdaA/omegaA)/MSamples

lambda and omega are predefined values, and MSamples in the number of samples in the data input (this is running a monte carlo simulation).

It SHOULD give me an expected percentage of increase.

Comment: Try wrapping it in brackets

Answer (score 2):

`>` means "greater than".

Run just the line `lambdaC/omegaC > lambdaA/omegaA` --- it will give you `TRUE` when `lambdaC/omegaC` is greater than `lambdaA/omegaA`, and `FALSE` otherwise.

When you sum TRUE/FALSE values, `TRUE` is counted as 1, and `FALSE` is counted as 0. So `sum(lambdaC/omegaC > lambdaA/omegaA)` is counting the number of times `lambdaC/omegaC` is greater than `lambdaA/omegaA`.

Answer (score 0):

In R `>` it is logical operator greater than and it gives boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` as result.

So, `lambdaC/omegaC > lambdaA/omegaA` will either give you `TRUE` of `FALSE` as result and when you try to sum, it will be considered as `1/0` respectively. So you will actually get `(0/1)/MSamples` as result which will be between `0 and 1` (0 inclusive and assuming `MSamples` is integer).

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem